# return the count of unique results in COL B, indexed by COL A

Tags: excel, vba

I'd prefer to do this with VBA, executed as needed versus formulas because I have 16000 rows.

Spreadsheet has entries listed a few hundred times in COL A. I need to see how many of those have a different value in COL B

```
COL A   COL B
A       1
A       2
A       1
A       1
A       2
A       1
A       1
A       1
B       1
B       1
B       1
B       1
B       1
```

Now return the count of unique results in COL B, indexed by COL A

```
COL A   COL B
A       2
B       1
```

I started with this and then my head started spinning ( I really hate VBA it doesn't click for me at all):

EDIT- Deleted that garbage I started with as it is no help to anyone. This is what I ended up using I had to modify @alter answer to only show me indexes  that were greater than 1 and then output it to a text file instead of msgbox ( the first time I ran it I had hundreds of msgboxs.

```
Sub CountUnique()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
    Dim keyMap As Object, values As Object
    Dim key As String, value As String
    Dim keysColumn As String, valuesColumn As String
    Dim row As Long
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim item As Object
    Dim outFile As String

    myFile = "C:\usercount.txt"
    Set keyMap = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    rowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    keysColumn = "C"
    valuesColumn = "E"

    For row = 2 To rowCount
        key = Range(keysColumn & row).Text
        value = Range(valuesColumn & row).Text
        If keyMap.Exists(key) Then
            Set values = keyMap.item(key)
            If values.Exists(value) = False Then values.Add value, ""
        Else
            Set values = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            values.Add value, ""
            keyMap.Add key, values
        End If
    Next row

    Open myFile For Output As #1
    For Each v In keyMap.keys
        key = v
        Set values = keyMap.item(key)
            If values.Count > 1 Then
               Write #1, key & ": " & values.Count
            End If
    Next v
    Close #1
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Something went wrong"
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't care how the results come back as long as I can copy and paste them, so anything but a message box would be nice.

Comment: This is not somewhere where you can just post your requirements and expect answers without at least describing what you've tried... You should be able to do this with a scripting.dictionary object - try that, and post back with code if you run into problems.

Comment: @TimWilliams I've been trying to do this for about 3 hours all of my efforts have been practically useless and I don't want to confuse what I am trying to do.

Comment: @pnuts I'm willing to entertain a formula. I just get weary because I've had workbooks with only a few hundred rows become nearly unusable because of VLOOKUPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution, just use a 2D dictionary. The first dimension is column A (the column you are indexing by), the second dimension is column B (the values). The nice thing about dictionaries is that they have an "Exists" function which will check if a key is already in use

```
Sub CountUnique()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
    Dim keyMap As Object, values As Object
    Dim key As String, value As String
    Dim keysColumn As String, valuesColumn As String
    Dim row As Long
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim item As Object

    Set keyMap = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    rowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    keysColumn = "A"
    valuesColumn = "B"

    For row = 2 To rowCount
        key = Range(keysColumn & row).Text
        value = Range(valuesColumn & row).Text
        If keyMap.Exists(key) Then
            Set values = keyMap.item(key)
            If values.Exists(value) = False Then values.Add value, ""
        Else
            Set values = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            values.Add value, ""
            keyMap.Add key, values
        End If
    Next row

    For Each v In keyMap.keys
        key = v
        Set values = keyMap.item(key)
        MsgBox key & ": " & values.Count
    Next v

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Something went wrong"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much the concept I had in mind I just can't stand VB it is completely alien to me.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
Sub Tester()
    CountUnique Range("A2:A10"), Range("d2")
End Sub


Sub CountUnique(rngIn As Range, rngOut As Range)

    Dim d As Object
    Dim c As Range, tmp, v, arr(), i As Long, ex, k

    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    For Each c In rngIn.Cells

        tmp = Trim(c.Value)
        v = Trim(c.Offset(0, 1).Value)

        If d.exists(tmp) Then
            arr = d(tmp)
            ex = False
            For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                If v = arr(i) Then
                    ex = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
            If Not ex Then
                ReDim Preserve arr(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) + 1)
                arr(UBound(arr)) = v
                d(tmp) = arr
            End If
        Else
            ReDim arr(0 To 0)
            arr(0) = v
            d(tmp) = arr
        End If
    Next c

    i = 0
    For Each k In d.keys
        rngOut.Offset(i, 0).Value = k
        arr = d(k)
        rngOut.Offset(i, 1).Value = Join(arr, ",")
        rngOut.Offset(i, 2).Value = 1 + (UBound(arr) - LBound(arr))
        i = i + 1
    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sure this is a good answer. But what I am trying to do seems so simple to me I could do it with a shell script... (OMG why didn't I just do it with a shell script I would have been done hours ago it was a CSV to begin with) in just a few lines. I hate VB. I don't understand the need to use obscure built in functions (obscure to me anyhow) to do something. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Dozens of ways to skin that cat, but you did ask ;-). Just use whatever works for you...

Answer (score 1):

You should possibly consider using a pivot table.  This will return the end result that you are looking for.  Just select the entire range, create a Pivot Table, and put both columns into the "Row Labels" area.

This eliminates the need for a lot of mind-bending VBA scripting.